# How to open chrome apps as a regular tab with its api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to develop a **packaged chrome app** (not extension) and hope to could open it as a regular tab like the image showing below.
[image]
I followed the official docs to make my first app:
http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html

But it can not show the four options which are open as **regular tab, pinned tab, window and full screen**.

After searched again and again in the chrome official site and SO or anywhere else in my time, I could not find out how to make it.

I think its the manifest file's job, but I could not find any clue in its description, either. 
http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html

Can somebody give me some hints?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the tab behavior for Chrome Packaged Apps, only in Chrome Hosted Apps. There are a lot of differences between them, but a very short and simplistic definition is:

- **Packaged Apps** are apps that look and feel as native apps. They have access to more powerful APIs that traditional web apps don't (like hardware devices, extended filesystem and much more). They are self-contained and usually have a good behavior when offline. They also run outside of the browser and the user doesn't see them as traditional web apps (as in running inside a browser);
- **Hosted Apps**, on the other hand, are web apps, living in a remote server, with a little more power than traditional web apps, but much less than packaged apps. They are launched from the browser and, in general, they require a network connection to work appropriately (ie, they are not self-contained).

Tab behavior makes sense for Hosted apps, because they run inside the browser, but not for Packaged apps, because they NEVER run as tabs.

If you want to develop a hosted app, [this is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide).

For Packaged apps, the doc is the one [you've mentioned](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html).

Comment: Thank you, I think what I want to implement is the Hosted Apps. But could you explain why there is no url in the address bar when opening this app, please? [Quick Note](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-note/mijlebbfndhelmdpmllgcfadlkankhok?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Comment: I believe that's a design decision based on the assumption that the user has no use for the URL of extensions and apps, which takes the form of `chrome-extension://long_alphanumeric_appid`.

Comment: Hi, @mangini. Thank you, finally I made it. I used `local_path` instead of `web_url` in the `app` node of manifest.json file. But as I know now, its a [legacy version](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html) for app development. Could I use some similar way to implement this feature at its new version?

Comment: No, there is no way because the new packaged apps have no relation with the browser (I didn't mention the old packaged apps because it is deprecated and won't be supported in the future).

Comment: I have seen [this news](http://lifehacker.com/5985924/chromes-app-launcher-runs-chrome-apps-on-your-desktop-available-on-dev-channel-now) yesterday, it seems that there are not so many packaged apps currently.

Comment: The new packaged apps are in developer preview mode - which is a great moment for developers to create great apps and get attention when the platform launches to the consumer. Currently, there is no way to list all packaged apps - on purpose to avoid customers installing them widely before the platform is ready for general consumption.

Comment: you could make hosted app act like work without internet if you store stuff in local storage(chrome.store api) and have all the other stuff like jpg included in app background.html. Could you also have another page like abc.htm that you can link to from background html? right.